# Can't see where multiple call of res caused the error : Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

I'm following a tutorial in the net. It's a MERN project with mongo/mongoose. When I have implemented the update function in the controller the following error has occured :

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

I've seen the answers about similar issue where they say it's because there are 2 or multiple calls of res (res.json(), res.send() etc..), but I don't see where must I change this in the following function :

```
module.exports.updateUser = async(req, res) => {
if (!ObjectID.isValid(req.params.id))
    return res.status(400).send("ID unknown : " + req.params.id);

try {
    await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate({
            _id: req.params.id
        }, {
            $set: {
                bio: req.body.bio
            }
        },
        (err, docs) => {
            if (!err)
                return res.send(docs);
            if (err)
                return res.status(500).send({ message: err });
        }
    )
} catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: err });
}
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that you've mixed up two different error handling patterns.

You don't need try/catch if you're using built in error handling of `findOneAndUpdate()`

```
await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate({
            _id: req.params.id
        }, {
            $set: {
                bio: req.body.bio
            }
        },
        (err, docs) => {
            if (!err)
                return res.send(docs);
            if (err)
                return res.status(500).send({ message: err });
        }
)
```

and if you are using try/catch, you don't need findOneAndUpdate's error handling:

```
try {
    const user = await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate({
            _id: req.params.id
        }, {
            $set: {
                bio: req.body.bio
            }
        })

    return res.send(user)
} catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: err });
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the solution and the explanation. the second case doesn't work though ..

Comment: ... it needs return res.send(docs); as in Mohsin's solution.

Comment: Ah good point.  I'll update the answer.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please change code like this:

```
module.exports.updateUser = async(req, res) => {
  if (!ObjectID.isValid(req.params.id))
      return res.status(400).send("ID unknown : " + req.params.id);
  
  try {
      const result = await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate({
              _id: req.params.id
          }, {
              $set: {
                  bio: req.body.bio
              }
          });
      return res.send(result);
  } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ message: err });
  }
  };
```

Comment: Thank you so much . it works now